# Skyrim: Ref ID for Pontious Uriel

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a new follower called Pontious Uriel, who shows up in altar I noticed in Breezehome after I installed the "Better Breezehome" mod. How do I find his refid?

Comment: ask the modder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the console, click on him, his RefID will be display at the top of the console. Make sure there aren't any invisible obstructions between you and him, try to get as close as possible.